# Kubeflow: access denied to Minio artifacts from the pipeline (run) graph view

Tags: rbac, minio, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I installed Kubeflow on my Docker Desktop Kubernetes. Everything seems to work so far, apart from the following problem:

When trying to access any artifacts (input/output, logs, etc.) from the Run dashboard (i.e. clicking on any step and selecting the correspoding link on the right - see attachement) I'm getting the "RBAC: access denied" message.

I can however log in to minio and access those artifacts manually.

Where do I set the authorization?
Thanks!

Cheers,
Slava

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mun0L.png)

P.S. I am happy to provide more details about the setup - just not quite sure what is relevant to the problem.
I am forwarding the central dashboard using the standard prescription (kubectl port-forward -n istio-system svc/istio-ingressgateway 8080:80 and accessing it on localhost:8080).